# How to turn off the camera on tab or view change

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

Camera doesn't turn off when change Tab/View

```js
render() {
  const { hasCameraPermission } = this.state;
  if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
    return <View><Button
         onPress={() => this.showCamera()}
           title="Show Camera"
          />
         </View>;
  } else if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  } else {
    return (
      <View>
        <Camera>
        </Camera>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In the view i have the button that can display the Camera. But once, the camera if turn on. When i change tab (tab nvigation) and come back to the view, i doesn't have the button, but a black screen. it seems the camera is not turn off.

Thank you

Comment: **Note:** Only one active Camera preview is supported currently. When using navigation, the best practice is to unmount previously rendered `Camera` component so next screens can use camera without issues.

Comment: Which camera component are you using?

Comment: I use expo-camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a specific component for displaying caméra.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on what you mean by this? I am having the same issues

Comment: Have tried doing this but nothing works. Looked at the Code for Expo BarCodeScanner and it seems like they never call the closeCamera or closePreview function from anywhere. It looks like it should be fixed from the Expo BarCodeScanner side